# uwsgi_master_fifo()/mkfifo(): Permission denied

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose, uwsgi

Well I am trying to get django aplication on a prodaction server using uwsgi and docker. On production server nginx is started but it does not configured for uwsgi. I install uwsgi using pip without virtual environment into docker. However when I try up service with django app I get `uwsgi_master_fifo()/mkfifo(): Permission denied [core/fifo.c line 112]`.

My uwsgi.ini:

```
[uwsgi]
http-socket    = :8000
chmod-socket   = 777
chdir          = /api/
module         = MenStore.wsgi:application
static-map     = /staticfiles=static

master          = true
processes       = 4
offload-threads = 4
vacuum          = true
harakiri        = 30
max-requests    = 10000
stats           = :9191

memory-report  = true
enable-threads = true
logger         = internalservererror file:/tmp/uwsgi-errors.log

post-buffering = 1

buffer-size = 16383

uid            = 1000
gid            = 1000

touch-reload = uwsgi-reload
master-fifo = uwsgi-fifo
```

My django app service into docker-compose file:

```
api: &api
    build:
      context: Backend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - "/root/MenStore/media/:/api/media/:rw"
    command: uwsgi --ini /api/uwsgi.ini
    depends_on:
      postgres:
        condition: service_healthy
      redis:
        condition: service_started
```

Comment: What is the ownership of the `/root/MenStore/media`? Because your uwsgi will run as uid/gid 1000. So if that user is not able to write in that mount, you get this.

Comment: If I will delete this line nothing is changed. I also get the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution. I added `RUN chmod 0777 [work_directory]` into my Dockerfile.